# one strange behavior of xmlrpc

Tags: python

Here is the code:
server part and called from machine 10.42.0.1:

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ()

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('10.42.0.1', 8000),
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler)

server.register_function(adder, 'add')

print('initialize finish')
server.serve_forever()
```

client part, and call from machine 10.42.0.2:

```
import xmlrpc.client
s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://10.42.0.1:8000')
print(s.add(2,3))
```

However, I've got the error message from machine 10.42.0.2:
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111]. And telnet 10.42.0.1 8000 also failed.

Then, I change this sentence:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('10.42.0.1', 8000),
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler)
```

to:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('', 8000),
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler)
```

And restart xmlrpc server, the xmlrpc client works this time. Then I change this sentence to:

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('10.42.0.1', 8001),
                        requestHandler=RequestHandler)
```

And open a new xmlrpc server, and change the client code to:

```
import xmlrpc.client
s = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://10.42.0.1:8001')
print(s.add(2,3))
```

And start a new xmlrpc client, the client now also works.

Anyone help me explain this strange phenomenon?
A bit like arp table not built.

Comment: In the 1st case did the server start? And this behavior is constantly reproducible?

Comment: yes. and now, everything seems working.